# An issue with replaceText

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following piece of code:

```
var aaa = "E";
aaa.replaceText("[E,e]", "a");
```

Trying to run it gives the following error:

> "TypeError: aaa.replaceText is not a function (line 56, file "test")"

Why?
How else can I make that string replacement?

Comment: Which do you want to use [`replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) or [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

Answer (score 1):

Using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

```
var aaa = "E";
const regex = /[Ee]/;

console.log(aaa.replace(regex, 'a'));
```